# Why mocking wcf services with soapui

Tags: wcf, soapui

I am trying to understand mocking the wcf services using SOAPUI.

Quoting from [smartbear's blog](http://blog.smartbear.com/soapui/eriks-quick-tip-using-mockservice-in-soapui/) this can be handy in

**Rapid Web Services Prototyping**

> Generate a complete static mock implementation from a WSDL in seconds
>   and add dynamic functionality using Groovy. This allows you to
>   implement and test clients much faster than if you had needed to wait
>   for the actual solution to get build.

**Client testing or development**

> Clients can be developed against the MockService and
>   tested without access to the live services.

So from this and some other blogs that I went through I understand that the Primary thing (by what I read) is to keep testing moving along before the service is available (I must say that I didn't get this actually. The service has to up before you sent up some mock requests and responses). Does it implies that the service should be available at the time we setting up this mocks so that we can play with them later on when it  is actually not available?

Also can we say that there won't be a difference between saving multiple test cases for a given service and mocking given the service is up and running (after all its service it is supposed to be running).

Comment: SoapUI website has additional information: https://www.soapui.org/testing-dojo/best-practices/api-mocking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on a large project where 3 different systems all traded data with services.  It was the same WSDL (an "industry standard", very complicated beast that didn't fit either of our systems particularly well), and we all had clients for sending data to the servers of the other systems.  Each dev/test team had to develop both a client and a service, and we didn't really understand mocks.
As you would expect, we all had our clients done before any of the services were ready.  And testing couldn't do anything for months. And when they could finally test (the day after the devs were able to get data to finally flow), things were a mess.

So I can't time-travel back to 2010 and save myself, but I CAN save YOU.

Here's where you still don't get it:

> The service has to up before you sent up some mock requests and
>   responses

You don't need the service to be up, built, coded, funded, or even approved.  The SoapUI Mock Service IS the service.  Rather, it's a very capable stand-in.  So once you have a WSDL, you can built the mock service, create some sample responses, and hit it with a client (possibly other instances of SoapUI).

So why do this? Lots of reasons.

Multiple dev teams, on different timelines.

Testing can proceed, yes.

Avoid surprises down the road (after code)  Just because we agreed to use this WSDL, doesn't mean that my data is what your system expects, and vice-versa. Let's find out now!

Examples:

- For the Armor field, the WSDL just says "string" but our system allows 25 chars and yours allows 45.
- We need you to send UserHighScore if you change LifetimeAchievements.  Otherwise it gets reset.
- I thought we agreed to put UserRank in the User Atributes tag, not the Power tag?
- UserRank needs Effective Date, otherwise it causes our side to delete all of the UserRank history.
- That's how it used to work.
- Stop sending us the same data that we just sent you. When you UPPERCASE our data that you just received, that ISN'T A CHANGE that you need to tell us about.

Ideally, the system would be developed first with mock services and SoapUI.  Once the WSDL is developed, stand up the mock service, then send submit sample requests via SoapUI.  Both test and dev should be involved.  Look at the data being sent from the SoapUI clients and build/script responses.  Spend a few days developing test cases.  Audit for invalid data, return realistic responses, make sure that you return failures as well as successes, and try to consider (and document) all expected failure scenarios, including time-outs (can be scripted with sleep() function in mock service).  The time-out scenario can be used to simulate load, so that you can see the impact on clients and infrastructure (we were able to tip over Layer7 gateways by sending transactions at a higher rate than the service could handle, if we kept at it for 30 minutes).
So use the mockservices as a joint workshop to hammer out the details of what your service-oriented solution will look like, THEN code it up.  You'll be glad you did.